# Decrease load time for data table page containing more than 500 transactions

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, tabs, datatables

1. Is there a way to decrease the load time of the page in IE just by using Data tables.
2. If we use server side pagination and sorting, can we also do a quick search on server side and also render only that particular tab instead of the whole page.

   `<h:panelGroup id="transactionsPanel">
   <h:dataTable>
   </h:dataTable>
   <ui:repeat value="#{backing.pages}" var="page" varStatus="current">
   <h:commandLink value="#{page}" actionListener="#{backing.page}"
    rendered="#{page != backing.currentPage}" >
    <f:ajax render="transactionsPanel"/>
    </h:commandLink>
   <ui:repeat>

    </h:panelGroup>`

The listener is called but the page is not updated to display the next page clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there a way to decrease the load time of the page in IE just by using Data tables.*

No.

At least, not without replacing IE by a more sane webbrowser. IE is known to have a poor HTML `<table>` renderer. This is a client problem, not a server (JSF) problem. You can confirm this by measuring the network traffic speed and browser HTML rendering speed.

---

> *If we use server side pagination and sorting, can we also do a quick search on server side and also render only that particular tab instead of the whole page.*

Just perform the search (by ajax) in server side as well.

I recommend to look at JSF component libraries instead of grabbing to loose jQuery plugins and cobbling loose scripts together. PrimeFaces for example has a lazily loadable `<p:dataTable>` which solves all your problems with just clean XHTML and JPA. See also [the lazy `<p:dataTable>` showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml) and [Efficient JSF Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382486/efficient-jsf-pagination).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. In our project we use only Mojarra  JSF. I have updated my question related to ajax call for a data table. The page does not get updated after the ajax call.