# Prime Faces DataTable search form

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

As told here [Efficient JSF Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382486/efficient-jsf-pagination) this is the best implementation when you have to show data from DB.

I'm going to implement a solution based on this http://hrycan.com/2012/03/28/primefaces-lazy-loading-datatable-for-jsf2/

lazy loading uses

```
public List<Record> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) { .....
```

I like to implement this situation

- Form with one field per col
- A search button
- A data table that will be updated when search is pressed, but use the filters indicated in form field.

**Is this possible and how to manage external filters(not in data table)??.** ??

---

```
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                            |
|Form with a lot of field more or less 1 for each column.    |
|                                                            |
|Serch button ; reset button                                 |
|                                                            |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                            |
|            Data table with pagination                      |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
```

---

Comment: You should rework your question.

Comment: @Jens is now a bit more clear?

Comment: I still don't get where you differ from the example? The example seems to do what you want? So what are you asking for?

Comment: You don't need lazy loading in first line.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech why?  If my search return 100 results I prefer a pagiantion of 10 of them at time. Or i'm missing something.

Comment: You don't need lazy loading for pagination. Those are 2 separate mechanisms.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech in lazy loading i have   public List<Car> load(int first, int pageSize but in normal pagination i have  getCars().

Comment: @ŁukaszLech but the focus of my question is to use the filters in a separate form, when search is pressed i need to update the filters.
I have implemented a possible ide but it has some problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811286/setter-of-managed-bean-not-called

Comment: Filters in separate form are just the normal input texts, on click you can filter the collection bound directly to the datatable, so really there's no need to use LazyDataModel, since all lazy loading is done externally